# Removing photo of CD album cover from iTunes library on my computer

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, ipod

I cannot remove a photo from my iTunes library to replace it with a another one and then sync the latest photo with my iPod.

The original photo seems to be embedded in the iTunes library and I cannot even sync/transfer that to my iPod. Going to the "artwork" tab in the iTunes library and "adding" another photo doesn't work as you can't see the "embedded" photo to replace it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The cannot sync part sounds a little worrying - i had sync issues when my ipod drive was dying. If your system also freezes while syncing, and its an ipod classic, chances are your drive is dying.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try copying out the files in question to a working directory, deleting them from itunes, then loading them into [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) and adding the new album art with mp3tag, then adding them back to itunes.

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: If it worked, please select it as the correct answer